# Killall command?

Tags: shell-script

I do not know how to use the killall command. My code is:

[image]

and I want to cancel the command after 'The mods have failed to download'.

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Paste the actual text into the question instead, and format it as code (by clicking on `{}` in the edit box).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't entirely understand from your code the problem. If you want to terminate the script in the **else** branch after the **echo**, why don't you use **exit** or **return** ?

Comment: See: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/55075)

Comment: I apologize for posting my code as an image but the indentation refused to come out correctly when I put in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you need is not `killall`. You need the `exit` command which exits your program. By adding `exit 1` as the last statement of your `else` branch the script will terminate

Let me just break this command down:

`exit` accepts 1 argument which is the exit status. Exit status of `1` indicates that your script encountered a problem, in this case the mods failed to download. If you don't want to send the error exit status to the OS you can simply do `exit`

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like you only want to kill your current script, not other programs. In that case, a simple

```
exit(1)
```

at the end of the `else` branch should do the trick.